# Public membership register built on SearchKit Grid - how to link to individual detail form?

Tags: searchkit, formbuilder

I have built a Membership Register using SearchKit / FormBuilder (https://cgdent.uk/civicrm/member-register-grid/). To enhance the Register, I would like to use the "Link" function in SK for the user to navigate to a detail record for the Individual member.
I anticipate creating a separate form, using Formbuilder, to display the selected individual detail record (which might, for instance, include an image or logo).
I cannot discover the syntax for the Link that will pass the id of the selected record to the detail form for public display. Is this even possible?
I am using CiviCRM 5.58.1 and Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an id to a search form by adding eg `/#?user_id=23`  See the [docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/creating-new-forms/#using-url-filters-in-search-forms) or [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/42810/225)

Comment: Thank you! That works well!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create a view using search kit and include the search kit in a form and use the id from the url to filter the result of the search kit to specific contact id